# ¿Cómo formatear números en ChartJS de tipo Donut o Pie?

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js

Quiero trabajar con gráficos ChartJs y me gustaria saber como formatear los números a mostrar en el gráfico, ya que no aparecen con formato, por ejemplo así como se muestra en la imagen, en lugar de que muestre 7000000, mostrará $7,000,000

```
var donutChartCanvas = $('#donutChart').get(0).getContext('2d')
var donutData        = {
  labels: [
      'Chrome',
      'IE',
  ],
  datasets: [
    {
      data: [7000000,500000],
      labels: ['70','50'],
      backgroundColor : ['#f56954', '#00a65a'],
    }
  ]
}
var donutOptions     = {
  maintainAspectRatio : false,
  responsive : true,

}
//Create pie or douhnut chart
// You can switch between pie and douhnut using the method below.
new Chart(donutChartCanvas, {
  type: 'doughnut',
  data: donutData,
  options: donutOptions,

})
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Para dar formato a los datos dentro de los tooltips podes utilizar [`options.plugins.tooltip`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html#tooltip), más precisamente [`options.plugins.tooltip.callbacks.label`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html#label-callback)

#### Ejemplo:

```js
var donutChartCanvas = document.querySelector('#donutChart').getContext('2d')
var donutData = {
  labels: [
    'Chrome',
    'IE',
  ],
  datasets: [{
    data: [7000000, 500000],
    backgroundColor: ['#f56954', '#00a65a'],
  }]
}
var donutOptions = {
  maintainAspectRatio: false,
  responsive: true,
  plugins: {
    tooltip: {
      callbacks: {
        label: function(context) {
          let label = context.label || '';
          if (context.parsed !== null) {
            label = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
              style: 'currency',
              currency: 'USD',
              minimumIntegerDigits: 2,
              maximumSignificantDigits: 2
            }).format(context.parsed);
          }
          return label;
        }
      }
    }
  },

}
//Create pie or douhnut chart
// You can switch between pie and douhnut using the method below.
new Chart(donutChartCanvas, {
  type: 'doughnut',
  data: donutData,
  options: donutOptions,

})
```

```html
<div>
  <canvas id="donutChart"></canvas>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
```